# How can i have a good frame quality with PHP5-FFMPEG?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, frame

I'm trying tu use PHP5-FFMPEG in my website, but when i try to take some frame of any movie, the quality of this frame is really poor...

Here's the simply way i use to write this frames into images.

```
  $frame = $mov->getFrame($_GET['frame']);
  $img = $frame->toGDImage();
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($img);
```

Can i have a better quality with this extension ? Or I have to invoke a ffmpeg command line?

Image link : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKXUj.jpg

Comment: You should probably add the picture to your question, so everybody can see what you consider "bad quality". It might be that it is related to the video.

Comment: how big is the movie size (not file size, actual size)? also, what settings to you use for the class (sometimes classes have default return sizes etc... that you can manually adjust)

Comment: I've tried with different videos resolution (Iphone resolution, or 800x600, etc...) and the problem is still the same. there's a kind of pixellisation

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing in the quality parameter for the imagejpeg function, for example:

```
imagejpeg($im, NULL, 75);
```

Try to use imagepng to not lose any quality in conversions but the resulting filesize will be big.

You'll also be battling against the actual quality of the video as well and the motion within it.

It's not easy and maybe impossible in your case to get good quality frames from video.

Comment: I've tried to change imagejpeg and imagepng quality, but it changed nothing. You can see on the image link, there's a "pixellisation" problem..